# linearly ordered family of sets cardinality greater than supremum of individual sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Does there exist a set $X$ linearly ordered by $\subset$ where $|\bigcup X|>\sup\{|x|:x\in X\}$? I'm having trouble thinking around constructing one.

I'm fairly certain that finite sets won't work, so I tried considering sets which can be built up inductively like $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, but then I think it makes the statement an equality since the supremum covers the limit case.

Is there a set or way one can be constructed which cannot be from this inductively building up? I would think that construction would then imply that it is bigger than the ordinals, a class, and make it not possible to be a set, but albeit my cardinal skills aren't as good as they could be.

Comment: You know what ordinals are? What is the union of the set of all countable ordinals?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Assuming that the undefined $F$ is a typo for $X$ (you have a better guess?} then $X=$ the set of all countable ordinals seems to be the example he wants: $|\bigcup X|=\aleph_1\gt\aleph_0=\sup\{|x|:x\in X\}$.

Comment: yes, I made a bit of a typo, fixed it up top. And yes, I think I see where I went wrong, for some reason I think I was thinking that the surpremum would be the next cardinal greater than $\aleph_0$ in that case, instead of $\omega+1$ which is then the same as $\aleph_0$, and not $\aleph_1$. That makes more sense now, thanks!